# Previous Data Remains on the Network Stream

Tags: .net, vb.net, networkstream

I'm currently building a file transfer application with some logging features. What it does is, every time a client connects or disconnects it sends logs (string message) to the server. The logging part is working fine but when I try to send files, the program messes up.

It seems that this is purely a server side issue. What happens is that the previous data; which is the string message for logging, sent from the client seems get stuck on the network stream. When I try to send a file after connecting to the server, I get an error which says, *illegal characters in path*.

**Here's a screenshot of the error.**

[image]

I believe that this happens because, as you can see on the screenshot above in the `FileName` variable, a part of the string ("is connected.") which was sent when the client connected was stuck on the network stream. hello.cpp is the name of the file being sent.

**Here's the code.**

```
Dim ClientSocket As TcpClient = CType(tcpSocket, TcpClient)

Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = ClientSocket.GetStream() 'This stream is
'for the logging part. This part here, I think causes the error because when I
'remove this and the conditions for the logging part, leaving the file sharing
'algorithm alone, the whole program works.

While FileSharingStarted

    If CBool(ClientSocket.Available) Then
        Dim ByteData(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        networkStream.Read(ByteData, 0, CInt(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
        fileLogMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteData)

        If fileLogMessage.Contains("is connected." & Environment.NewLine) Then

            'This block here is for logging purposes. It receives the string 
            'message sent by the client when it connects and does some stuffs.

        ElseIf fileLogMessage.Contains("is disconnected." & Environment.NewLine) Then

            'This block here is for logging purposes again. It receives the 
            'string message sent by the client when it disconnects and then 
            'does some stuffs.

        Else

            'This part is for receiving the file sent by the client.

            Dim FileName, FilePath As String
            Dim FileLength As Long
            Dim binaryReader As New BinaryReader(ClientSocket.GetStream())

            FileName = binaryReader.ReadString()
            FileLength = binaryReader.ReadInt64()
            FilePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\home", FileName)

            Dim FileData(8092) As Byte
            Dim TotalData As Long = 0
            Dim ReadBytes As Integer = -1

            Using FileStream As New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                FileSharingStatusBar.Panels.Item(1).Text = "Receiving file . . ."

                Do Until TotalData = FileLength
                    ReadBytes = ClientSocket.GetStream.Read(FileData, 0, FileData.Length())
                    FileStream.Write(FileData, 0, ReadBytes)
                    TotalData += ReadBytes
                Loop
            End Using

            MessageBox.Show("File received.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            FileSharingStatusBar.Panels.Item(1).Text = "Idle."
        End If
    End If

End While
```

I'm just curious why does this happen. Am I missing something here? Any explanation or suggestion to sort this one out would be highly appreciated. Please enlighten me. :)

Comment: How are you determining where each message in the stream begins and ends?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `networkStream` and all its associated code? Are you able to read the whole file successfully? I ask this because your image shows a very huge file size (well over a Gigabyte).

Comment: @AlexEssilfie Yes. I can successfully receive a file. That's not the actual size of the file. hello.cpp is just 168  Kb. I guess that happens because of the loop. Its part of the problem, but I think it will be solved when I'll be able to successfully deal with network stream problem.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Errrm, the message sent is in constant size. Pardon me, but I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: So when you send the "log" messages, you pad them to the exact same length of bytes as the file transfer messages?

Comment: @StevenDoggart No, the size of the log messages are in constant size. Constant strings coming from the client side. Those log messages are only sent when a client connects or disconnects. While the files sent varies on size.

Comment: @RyklonZen: Your log messages are constant in length so that fixes one thing. Next question is how do you find the name of the file in the stream? Do you 'skip' some bytes? are the names fixed length? how do you determine where a file name starts and where it ends?

Comment: Point being, you seem to be under the assumption that when you write two strings on the client-side of the socket, and then read once on the server-side of the socket, that you'll only get the first string that was sent.  Socket communication doesn't work that way.  It's just a seamless stream of data.  When you read on the server-side, you may get 1 message, or a partial message, or multiple messages.  You have to format your messages in a way where you know where they begin and end when you receive them on the other side.

Comment: @StevenDoggart You have a point. Maybe I'm missing something about the network stream. I'm assuming that when I send a string over the network, after the receiving that data on the other side, the stream would will clear or empty itself. Is this not so? That's my current implementation. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I would be glad if you lead me the right path. :)

Comment: @AlexEssilfie I'm expecting that the network stream would clear itself when the server successfully receives the data, so that when the client sends a file, only the file name of the client will be stored on the network stream during another pass of the outer loop. The problem is, its not happening as far as the screenshot is concerned. `FileName = binaryReader.ReadString()` is the code I use to determine the file name of the file being received. My current understanding is that the network stream should clear or empty itself after a data is received. Is this not so? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that after you read the data, the next time you read from the stream, the same data will not be returned again.  Your position in the stream is automatically moved forward every time you read from the stream.  The problem, though, seems to be that by the time the server reads from the stream, the client has already sent multiple messages (in your example, a log message followed by a file transfer message).  When your server application reads the stream, it is not parsing apart the multiple messages and handling them individually.  Also, as I mentioned in a comment above, your server application needs to handle the fact that it may receive partial messages as well.  It needs to buffer the communication as it comes in and only process the messages once it has received the complete message data.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your replies, I should check my code and see what's wrong with it, following both suggestions of @Alex Esselfie and yours. Thanks for the time and patience. :)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with network streams, I believe you are right on your assumption of the stream clearing itself out <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978965#comment21042865_14978965)</sup>.

One other thing I have observed with network streams is that if one or more successive writes are performed, those writes are all put together and will not be cleared until the receiving end reads the entire stream to the end. What this means for you is that it may not be possible to distinguish between messages if more than one message is sent before the recipient reads the stream.

One way around this is to insert placeholders in your stream to mark the start and/or end of distinct messages. If that is done, your program will be able to determine where one chunk of data starts and where it ends. Implementing placeholders, in my opinion, should free you of the trouble you are currently experiencing.

**Sample Implementation**
***Note:*** Code in italics may be incorrect

```
Dim placeholder As Byte() = New Byte() {&H00, &H01, &HFE, &HFF}
Dim message As New List(Of Byte)()
Dim data As Byte()

Do While True
    data = stream.ReadBytes(1024)
    If data.Skip(data.Length - placeholder.Length).SequenceEquals(placeholder) Then
        message.AddRange(data.Take(data.Length - placeholder.Length)
        Exit Do
    Else
        message.AddRange(data)
    End If
Loop

' do something with the message read
```

What this does is that it reads the stream until it reads a chunk of data which ends with the placeholder signature then it stops and does something with the message that has been read from the stream.

Of course in your implementation you could have multiple concatenated messages so you'll have to have a way of preserving bytes from the next message that were 'accidentally' read. You also will have to do a pattern matching of the chunk of data read instead of checking if the beginning/end matches the placeholder.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. I'm just wondering why this is happening. I mean, I'm just sending a constant string "Ryklon is connected.", like that. I guess they're being handled individually like what @Steven Doggart said. I tried reading the number of bytes sent and its the exact number of bytes of the string sent except for the newline character, after another pass of the other loop, there are no bytes read. Maybe the client is sending white spaces? I don't really know, that's another theory. I guess, I should check the code further. Anyways, thanks for your patience and time. :)